# Scala: Problems with erasure on overriding equals function for parametrized classes

Tags: scala, manifest, equals, type-erasure

I'm having troubles on understanding well how to use manifests.

That's my problem:
I've creat a new parametrized class C and tryed to override equals like this:

```
override def equals(that:Any)=that match{
 case that:C[T] => true /*do smth else not relevant*/
 case _ => false
}
```

Of course I recieve the "warning: non variable type-argument T in type pattern C[T] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure". I  tryied so using manifests like I was using in many other functions:

```
override def equals(that:Any)(implicit manifest:Manifest[T])=that match{
 case that:C[T] => true
 case _ => false
}
```

But I recieved the "error: method equals overrides nothing" message.

I don't know how to fix this. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't fix it.  Welcome to the joys of smooth interoperation with java.  The only way to improve equals from `def equals(x: Any): Boolean` is to write a different method.

I'm always trying to convince martin that we should implement == desugaring differently, aiming at something like "def decentEquals[T](x: T)(implicit equiv: Equiv[T])" with default implicits and bridge methods to make it seamless unless you care, but he thinks equality tests shouldn't get any slower.

Answer (score 4):

Just an adjunct to *@extempore*'s answer; it is entirely possible to write **null-safe** equals methods which may be type safe. Have a look at [**Scalaz** `Identity`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Identity.scala) ([and examples](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/ExampleEqual.scala))

```
new Fruit ≠ new Orange //does not compile
new Apple ≟ new Apple  //compiles!
```

Being based on types, it would require any parameterization to be equal also (i.e. `C[T] == C[U] iff T =:= U`

---

Of course, the problem with trying to override a method:

```
def foo(bar : Bar) : Baz
```

With this:

```
def foo(bar : Bar) ( implicit bat : Bat) : Baz
```

Is that **this does not constitute overriding**. Because the method has a different *signature* you have *overloaded* the method instead. Which is why it's nice that scala requires the `override` modifier: otherwise you might not have noticed that the code was not doing what you thought it was!

Comment: `[T] == C[U] iff C =:= U` isn't supposed to be `T =:= U` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
  override def equals(that:Any)= {
    that match{            
      case that:C[x] => true
      case _ => false                                     
    }
  }
```

will compile, but I don't think it does what you want.  You're trying to see if the type-parameters match (I assume), but I don't know how (or if) you can do that. (Edit: reading more of the literature, I think you cannot.  You cannot, for obvious reasons, override a non-manifest-aware function with a manifest-aware one).